# Returning source observable value after inner observable emits value

Tags: rxjs

Within an observable chain, I need to perform some async work, then return the source value to the next observable so I had to `pipe(mapTo(x))` after the async work.

A more complete example:

```
// fake async work with just 1 null value
someAsyncWork = () => of(null)

of('1', '2', '3').pipe(
  // some async work
  concatMap(no => someAsyncWork().pipe(mapTo(no))),
  concatMap(no => `Some async work [${no}] done!`)
).subscribe(message => console.log(message))
```

I cannot use `tap(no => someAsyncWork())` because that would cause the next observable to run before `someAsyncWork()` returns.

While my current approach works, it somewhat clutters the code...and I have this pattern repeated in many places within the codebase.

Question: Anyway to do this without `pipe(mapTo(no))` - in a more concise/readable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest thing to do would be to write your own pipeable operator.

For example:

```ts
const concatTap = <T>(project: (value: T) => Observable<any>) =>
  concatMap((value: T) => project(value).pipe(mapTo(value)));
```

However, that assumes the observable for the async operation emits only a single value. To guard against multiple values being emitted you could do something like this:

```ts
const concatTap = <T>(project: (value: T) => Observable<any>) =>
  concatMap((value: T) => concat(project(value).pipe(ignoreElements()), of(value)));
```

You could use `concatTap` like this:

```ts
of('1', '2', '3').pipe(
  concatTap(() => someAsyncWork()),
  concatMap(no => `Some async work [${no}] done!`)
).subscribe(message => console.log(message));
```

I'm sure you could choose a better name than I did. `concatTap` was the first thing that popped into my head. Naming things is hard.

Comment: Thanks! looks like this is the solution. However, I tried the example, and got "TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'." at "project(value)". Will try to figure this out and mark as correct answer once i understand how this works. :-)

Comment: It seems it just needs `T` to be specified for the `value` parameter: `(value: T) => ...`. I've updated the answer.